# Get Connection object while using SessionFactory.getCurrentSession() in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-4.x, hibernate-5.x

I'm trying to get `Connection` object in Hibernate when `SessionFactory.getCurrentSession()` is used.

**Source code**

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DatabaseMetaData;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl;

public class SOExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
        SessionFactory  sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().configure().build());
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        Connection connection = ((SessionImpl) session).connection();
        // doing operation on connection object as per my requirement
        DatabaseMetaData databaseMetaData = connection.getMetaData();
        System.out.println(databaseMetaData.getDatabaseProductName());
    }
}
```

**Stacktrace**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy24 cannot be cast to org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl
    at com.SOExample.main(SOExample.java:20)
```

`getCurrentSession()` gives `Proxy` object of `Session` so It can't cast it to `SessionImpl` so what are the other ways to get `Connection` object. Or How to `SessionImpl` from Proxy object.

---

Other option I tried but it says `getConnectionProvider()` method not found.

```
SessionFactoryImplementor sessionFactoryImplementation = (SessionFactoryImplementor) session.getSessionFactory();
ConnectionProvider connectionProvider = sessionFactoryImplementation.getConnectionProvider();
try {
    Connection connection = connectionProvider.getConnection();
} catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**Note**: I'm using **hibernate-core-5.0.5.Final.jar**

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In **Hibenate** 5 we need to do things a  little bit different (for more details check https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html):

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistry;
import org.hibernate.boot.MetadataSources;
import org.hibernate.boot.Metadata;
import org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.spi.ConnectionProvider;
import org.hibernate.jdbc.Work;


public class Htest {

    public static void main(String ... args) throws SQLException {
        StandardServiceRegistry standardRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
                .configure("hibernate.cfg.xml")
                .build();

        Metadata metadata = new MetadataSources( standardRegistry )
                .addAnnotatedClass(TesEntity.class)
                .buildMetadata();

        SessionFactory sessionFactory = metadata.getSessionFactoryBuilder()
                .build();

        //one way to get connection version 5.0.2
        Connection c = sessionFactory.
                getSessionFactoryOptions().getServiceRegistry().
                getService(ConnectionProvider.class).getConnection();

        Session sess = null;
        try {
            sess = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        } catch (org.hibernate.HibernateException he) {
            sess = sessionFactory.openSession();
        }


        //If you are using latest version 5.2.3 you can use this line below
        //Connection c =  ((SessionImpl)sess.getSession()).connection();
        System.out.println(c.getMetaData().getDatabaseProductName());

        //another way to get connection
        sess.doWork(new Work() {
            @Override
            public void execute(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
                //connection accessible here
                System.out.println(connection.getMetaData().getDatabaseProductName());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

My configuration to derby db if you wan to test code.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/mytest;create=fasle</property>
        <!-- <property name="connection.username"/> -->
        <!-- <property name="connection.password"/> -->

        <!-- DB schema will be updated if needed -->
        <!-- <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property> -->
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Output of this app :

[image]

Comment: Is there any other way? I want it separately coz I'm passing that object in other class and methods.

Comment: I have updated code. Please check maybe this solution will be acceptable for you.

Comment: There ain't any method `session.getSession()`

Comment: Have you look to the code? This line Connection c =  ((SessionImpl)sess.getSession()).connection(); I think that's what you want.

Comment: Thats what I'm talking about there ain't method `getSession()` for `sess.getSession()`

Comment: Apologies I was using latest version of hibernate 5.2.3, this explains why i couldn't understood what was wrong. I suggest to change in existing code `Connection c` variable to `Connection c = sessionFactory.
                getSessionFactoryOptions().getServiceRegistry().
                getService(ConnectionProvider.class).getConnection();`

Comment: This is working fine. Can you please update your code with `Connection c = sessionFactory. getSessionFactoryOptions().getServiceRegistry(). getService(ConnectionProvider.class).getConnection();` so I can accept it. Thanks